# Domain names with dots at the end

Tags: dns, rfc

What is the difference between:

```
domainname
```

and

```
domainname.
```

?

For instance, let's suppose `msn.com` and `msn.com.`. I tried both here:

http://http-headers.online-domain-tools.com/link/d83cbgIenbU0KGj3/

http://http-headers.online-domain-tools.com/link/d83d3g2kZ1ioLns4/

From the example above we can see that both domain names are valid. However, they are obviously not the same because the responses are different.

I believe that [RFC 1035](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) (p. 7) defines domain names. Yet, the grammar does not allow dot at the end of a domain name.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
domainname.
```

Is the [fully qualified domain name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name)

Domain names ending in a dot are absolute where as the ones not ending in a dot are relative.

There's a catch though... The [stub resolver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolver_%28DNS%29#DNS_resolvers) default behaviour is to consider a request for any domain with at least one dot in it as being a request for an absolute domain.

So what actually happens is:

- when you type `msn.com` in your browser your stub resolver will send a dns query for `msn.com.` and then your browser will send a HTTP request to one of the IPs provided by the dns response
- when you type `msn` the domain is considered relative to your resolver's search list (see the search directive in your /etc/resolv.conf). If the search list is `search foo.com bar.com` your stub resolver will send a dns query for `msn.foo.com.` If that fails it will then send a dns query for `msn.bar.com.` If one of the previous dns queries succeeded your browser will send a HTTP request to one of the IPs provided by the dns response.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I was just pointing out that it might be caused by Microsoft's DNS server (as you can clearly see by visiting microsoft.com.)
I don't have a Windows Server instance here to try it out, can you confirm this may be caused from that?