# Adding a custom domain in PythonAnywhere does not work

Tags: django, pythonanywhere

I added my application to pythonanywhere, now I'm trying to add a custom domain but I can not get a positive result.

My change I've added in pythonanywhere looks like this. Under my hidden field is my domain name.
[image]

According to the [documentation](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/CustomDomains#configuring-the-domain-at-the-domain-registrar), I added a CNAME record (at my domain provider, it looks like this.).

[image]

But after entering in the address www.ka ....pl I am not being redirected to my django application in pythonanywhere.

This is my first time when i added my domain, how to fix this error (so that my application will appear after entering the domain), any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you trying flushing your DNS cache?

Comment: You might just need to wait for a while -- DNS changes can take a while to propagate across the internet.

Comment: were you able to solve the problem???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting up your CNAME, you need to end its value with a dot. to be absolute

```
CNAME: webapp-*****.pythonanywhere.com.
```

Otherwise it will be relative to your custom domain and end up like this :

```
webapp-*****.pythonanywhere.com.$DOMAIN
```

See [Domain names with dots at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480767/domain-names-with-dots-at-the-end)