# Custom domain under pythonanywhere not working

Tags: python, dns, subdomain, cname, pythonanywhere

I want to host a django web application to pythonanywhere. I have a domain in godaddy. I followed the instructions in this [link](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/CustomDomains). Under the DNS management page in godaddy, I setup the CNAME as follows

[image]

Once the CNAME was set, under the web section in pythonanywhere, I get the following warning

[image]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I followed the instructions as it was in the docs.

When I try to load the website I get this message

[image]

Why is my webapp not loading? Please help me

Other links similar to my problem but with no answers:
[Adding a custom domain in PythonAnywhere does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55087080/adding-a-custom-domain-in-pythonanywhere-does-not-work)

Comment: How long did you wait after making the DNS change?  It can take a couple of hours for DNS changes to propagate over the Internet.  Another thing to look for is if you have any other records in GoDaddy with the name set to "www" -- for example, A records.

Comment: Hi. The website works now. There was no problem with the way I set up the CNAME. I guess the problem was the setting up the web app itself. I deleted the app from the dashboard and started the process again. It worked properly.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I've been doing it.

Originally there is an entry that looks like this

`cname | www | @ | 1 Hour`

Now what you need to do is to change the `'@'` to `webapp-xxxxxx.pythonanywhere.com`

`cname | www | webapp-xxxxxx.pythonanywhere.com | 1 Hour`

Give it time. 48 hours maximum.

If you want to also have the "naked link" like 'yourdomain.com' without 'www', then you can register your domain at nakedssl.com and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

When setting up your CNAME, you need to end its value with a dot. to be absolute

```
CNAME: webapp-*****.pythonanywhere.com.
```

Otherwise it will be relative to your custom domain and end up like this :

```
webapp-*****.pythonanywhere.com.$DOMAIN
```

PythonAnywhere documentation is not particularly clear about that.

See [Domain names with dots at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480767/domain-names-with-dots-at-the-end)