# how to use multiple arguments for mutliple R script?

Tags: r, bash, arguments

i'm new to bioinformatic and i try to use multiple R script in a bash script :

```
#!/bin/bash

#Pathway of your script
Rscript /home/administrateur/Bureau/guillaume/fichier_workflow/Script/script_analyse_complete_seq.R $1 $2 $3 &&
#$1 : pathway of the file to use
#$2 : Mabsilico table record pathway  + filename
#$3 : fasta file record pathway + filename


#Pathway of your folder containing file you record previously to apply vquest function
cd /home/administrateur/Bureau/guillaume/fichier_workflow

vquest --species human --receptorOrLocusType IG --fileSequences $4
#$4  pathway of the file to use for vquest
#if needed parameter here can be changer depending of what you are working on


mv vquest_airr.tsv $5
#$5 : new file name

rm Parameters.txt

#Pathway of your script
cd /home/administrateur/Bureau/guillaume/fichier_workflow/Script

#Pathway of your script
Rscript /home/administrateur/Bureau/guillaume/fichier_workflow/Script/script_after_vquest.R $6 $7 $8 $9 $10
#$6 : pathway of the vquest file
#$7 : proportion file record pathway + filename
#$8 : IGHV proportion file record pathway + filename
#$9 : IGKV proportion file record pathway + filename
#$10 : IGLV proportion file record pathway + filename


#Pathway of your script
cd /home/administrateur/Bureau/guillaume/fichier_workflow/Script

#Pathway of your script
Rscript /home/administrateur/Bureau/guillaume/fichier_workflow/Script/script_opti_comp_tableau.R $11 $12 $13 $14

#$11 : Full pathway of the first table to compare
#$12 : Full pathway of the second table to compare
#$13 : pathway to record similarity table + filename 
#$14 : pathway to record difference table + filename

echo "travail brute termine"
```

but when users want to use it, it look like this :

```
sh bash_fusion.sh /home/administrateur/PycharmProjects/Roxane_10X/HD618_naive/outs/all_contig_annotations.csv /home/administrateur/Bureau/guillaume/fichier_workflow/test_fusion/MabSilico_HD618_naive.csv /home/administrateur/Bureau/guillaume/fichier_workflow/test_fusion/HD618_naive.fasta /home/administrateur/Bureau/guillaume/fichier_workflow/test_fusion/HD618_naive.fasta /home/administrateur/Bureau/guillaume/fichier_workflow/test_fusion/vquest_HD618_naive.tsv /home/administrateur/Bureau/guillaume/fichier_workflow/test_fusion/vquest_HD618_naive.tsv /home/administrateur/Bureau/guillaume/fichier_workflow/test_fusion/proportion_clonotype_HD618_naive.csv /home/administrateur/Bureau/guillaume/fichier_workflow/test_fusion/IGHV_HD618_naive.csv /home/administrateur/Bureau/guillaume/fichier_workflow/test_fusion/IGKV_HD618_naive.csv /home/administrateur/Bureau/guillaume/fichier_workflow/test_fusion/IGLV_HD618_naive.csv /home/administrateur/Bureau/guillaume/fichier_workflow/test_fusion/IGHV_HD618_naive.csv /home/administrateur/Bureau/guillaume/fichier_workflow/test_fusion/IGHV_HD619_naive.csv /home/administrateur/Bureau/guillaume/fichier_workflow/test_fusion/same_HD618vsHD619_naive.csv /home/administrateur/Bureau/guillaume/fichier_workflow/test_fusion/dif_HD618vsHD619_naive.csv
```

And well it's quite long, and all argument are positionnal, i want to make it more friendly for the users like putting the arguments in a extern file that bash would read or any other idea to make it simple for the users.

Thanks in advance for your answer !

Comment: Are these really 16 unique values? If they are all separate value and are all required for running the script, I'm not sure there's a way to make the input any easier. You mention using a file. Do you want them to write the 16 values on separate lines of the file? If so, maybe these ideas could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559500/how-read-line-by-line-in-bash-and-assign-the-value-to-a-variable

Comment: Thanks for your answer, for the moment i don't use a separate file, i use one bash script for one R script to only use 4 argument, but since i want to use all R script in one go i try to find an other way than write 16 arguments each type i wanna use it, or maybe find a simple way to do it

Comment: do you really run `script1.R $1 $2 $3 $4` (same for `script2.R`) twice?

Comment: i run them separatly when i need them, but now i wanted to run them all and optimise arguments

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bash script that somewhat simplifies your endeavor:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# Usage: quux.sh script1.R ... scriptN.R arg1 arg2 ... argX
# Effect:
#   Rscript script1.R arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4
#   Rscript script2.R arg5 arg6 arg7 arg8
# ... in groups of 4

SCRIPTS=()
for opt in "${@}" ; do
    if [[ "${opt}" == *".R" ]]; then
        SCRIPTS=("${SCRIPTS[@]}" "${opt}")
        shift
    else
        break
    fi
done

for SCRIPT in "${SCRIPTS[@]}" ; do
    if [[ $# -le 1 ]]; then
        break
    fi
    echo Rscript ${SCRIPT} $1 $2 $3 $4
    if [[ $# -le 4 ]]; then
        break
    else
        shift 4
    fi
done

if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "! Unhandled arguments: ${@}" > /dev/stderr
    exit 1
fi
```

```bash
### quick setup, just for demonstration
$ touch script1.R script2.R script3.R script4.R

### default usage
$ ./quux.sh script*.R path1 path2 path3 path4 path5 path6 path7 path8 path9 path10 path11 path12
Rscript script1.R path1 path2 path3 path4
Rscript script2.R path5 path6 path7 path8
Rscript script3.R path9 path10 path11 path12

### partial runs, not sure if your R scripts work with this:
$ ./quux.sh script*.R path1 path2 path3 path4 path5 path6
Rscript script1.R path1 path2 path3 path4
Rscript script2.R path5 path6

### if we run out of scripts before arguments, emit an error
$ ./quux.sh script1.R path1 path2 path3 path4 path5 path6
Rscript script1.R path1 path2 path3 path4
! Unhandled arguments: path5 path6
```

Assumptions:

- always `Rscript ...`, and `Rscript` is found in the user's `PATH`
- always groups of 4

Notes:

- normal script handling applies, this `quux.sh` needs to be marked executable (`chmod +x quux.sh`); I am using `./quux.sh` since I'm in the current directory, but if you move it to somewhere in the user's `PATH`, then this should not be necessary
- I'm using bash (not `sh`) with its arrays and `[[` conditionals, `/bin/sh` won't work with this
- if you provide more scripts than necessary, it silently does not use the trailing scripts, no error-checking here, though it will error if arguments are un-handled (demoed above)

Comment: Thanks you very much for your help ll try it !

Comment: i tried your script but i encoutered a problem : on the first script one of the argument isnt for an R script but for an other command, also the user still have to write down all arguments and i try to avoid that (like filling a file possibly read by the bash script or any other idea) thanks for your help.

Comment: i'm sorry i m not really good at explaining, i ll show exactly what i have if it help

Comment: *(Many typos in the prev comment, fixed.)* Non R script: your example is incomplete then, how am I supposed to know to support arbitrary script files? If the commands you run are always the same, remove the dynamic-scripts portion of this. Arguments: I don't know how to improve something when you've given no examples for what they look like. I'm not sure how having them type them into a file (your suggestion) is any more convenient than typing them on the command line where tab-completion can really simplify the effort.